# Will java app run on Liberty Profile and WAS

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

At a customer we use WAS to develop and run web apps. The problem is that WAS running locally is not the fasted web server.
With the release of Websphere Liberty Profile (WLP) it could be a good alternative to run on our local development environment.

Will Java apps developed on WLP run on a 'real' WAS server? Without changes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Java EE applications developed on Liberty will run on WebSphere Application Server traditional without changes because both are Java EE compliant application servers.  Because of it's composabilility, smaller size and faster starter startup time,  developing applications on Liberty and deploying them on WebSphere Application Server traditional is a common paradigm and can provide a good development experience.

Comment: This is not true at the moment (WAS 8.5.5.7), if you will use any of the Java EE 7 features which are fully supported in Liberty, but currently not in traditional WebSphere Application Server. So you have to limit features to only Java EE 6.

Answer (score 2):

If you develop on Liberty with a goal to deploy on traditional WebSphere Application Server, and limit your applications to the EE6 web profile programming model (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_webProfile-6.0.html) your application is  likely to run unmodified on traditional WebSphere Application Server.

The WebSphere Migration Toolkit can help answer some of theses kinds of questions by analyzing your application:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/config.html

Comment: ...or Java EE 7: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_javaee-7.0.html

Comment: Wouldn't EE7 on the liberty/development side present significantly more risk in running "unchanged" on traditional/full WAS @EE6?
(p.s. Hi Brett)

Comment: You're absolutely right, my comment is invalid.  (Hi, Eric :-))